# jQuery Ajax grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are starting a new ASP.NET MVC application and want to use an 
jQuery Ajax grid.

I came across following options:

- jqGrid (better than Flexigrid because it supports editable cells)
- Flexigrid (looks better than jqGrid)
- tablesorter
- Ingrid
- jqGridView
- OTHERS?

**Which is the best choice for jQuery Ajax grid ?** 
Which is the most popular jQuery grid/table ?

Comment: dup?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993588/css-whats-the-best-way-of-creating-a-9x9-sudoku-grid/993597#993597

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For flat view-only grids I would simply use a tablesorter. Once you configure your CSS properly, it can look great, support sorting, alternating colors, etc.

If you need editing, I would go with jqGrid. I experienced several issues with Flexigrid and (as you can see) it is not that actively maintained. **jqGrid**, on the other hand, is being actively developed and inline with the jQuery UI components including themes support.

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of [jQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), out of the options you listed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we just solved this problem on an application that we are currently building. I would  strongly suggest using [YUI datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/). I know your probably thinking 'but we are using just jquery' - at least have a [squiz at this article](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/10/15/datatable-260-part-one/), which is a very good rundown of  its capabilities. I think that once you have included all the different jquery plugins to achieve a jQuery UI you could have the entire YUI library which is in my honest opinion far supirior. Also both jQuery and YUI live together in perfect harmony

Comment: Also I had a bit of a rant about this on another answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986022/feeding-net-mvc-views-the-jquery-ui-way/986167#986167

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/) could take the cake for best jQuery datatable and its oss!